# Relation involving lengths determined by a line (through the incenter?) of a triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

From ["A Beautiful Journey through Olympiad Geometry"](http://www.olympiadgeometry.com/the-book.html):

> **Part II. Problem 2.** Let $I$ be the incenter of $\triangle ABC$. Let $\ell$ be a line [through $I$?] parallel to $\overline{AB}$, that intersects the sides $\overline{CA}$ and $\overline{CB}$ at $M$ and $N$, respectively. Prove that $$|\overline{AM}| + |\overline{BN}| = |\overline{MN}|$$

I think this problem is wrong because I could prove that $|\overline{MN}|$ is not equal to $|\overline{AM}|+|\overline{BN}|$. And what is the role of incenter here?

---

*Edited by @Blue.* Note: The source does not mention that $\ell$ passes through $I$. This appears to be a simple omission, as the stated relation is readily shown to hold only with that assumption.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: I assume that the line $\ell$ should go through $I$. Also, could you maybe not use a capital $I$ and a small $l$, they are confused way to easily. If you have a proof that this is wrong, why not give it, then we can see what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Let's change the notation somewhat so that the symmetry of the figure is more apparent.  Specifically, draw lines $A_c B_c$, $B_a C_a$, $C_b A_b$ parallel to $AB$, $BC$, $CA$ respectively, and such that all pass through the incenter $I$.  Then this creates three similar triangles:  $$\triangle A_c I C_a \sim \triangle A_b B_a I \sim \triangle I B_c C_b \sim \triangle ABC.$$  Consequently, the resulting figure also contains three parallelograms, $$AA_bIA_c, \quad BB_cIB_a, \quad CC_aIC_b.$$  But since the distance between each pair of parallel lines is the same and is the inradius $r$, the parallelograms are actually rhombi, and in particular $$AA_c = A_cI, \quad BB_c = B_cI,$$ thus $$A_cB_c = AA_c + BB_c,$$ which proves the desired relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I'll prove the following:

> Given that $\overline{MN}\parallel\overline{AB}$, then
>    $$a+b=m+n \quad\iff\quad \text{$P$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$}$$

[image]

The parallelism condition tells us right away that
$$\angle 1 \cong \angle 2 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \angle 3 \cong \angle 4$$

So ...

$$\begin{align}
a+b = m+n \quad&\iff\quad \text{($\Rightarrow$, we may assume; $\Leftarrow$ from below, we deduce) $a=m$ and $b=n$.} \\
\quad&\iff\quad \text{$\triangle AMP$ and $\triangle BNP$ are isosceles} \\
\quad&\iff\quad \angle \theta \cong \angle 1\cong\angle 2 \quad\text{and}\quad \angle \phi \cong \angle 3\cong\angle 4 \\
\quad&\iff\quad \text{$\overline{AP}$ and $\overline{BP}$ are angle bisectors} \\
\quad&\iff\quad \text{$P$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$}
\end{align}$$